# Beautiful vs Beautifull

Tags: spelling

I am always confused between **beautiful** (ends with single L) and **beautifull** (ends with double L).

I noticed that in the dictionaries it's written with one L but maybe also the second form is correct and just not considered common and hence the dictionaries don't mention it.

In my phone automatic corrector both of the options do exist, and on Google I saw unclear answers for it. I would like to know a clear answer for this question.

Comment: How many dictionaries online have you found the spelling *beautifull* in?

Comment: You should delete the option with two els from your phone automatic corrector thingie.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: The OP shouldn't be blamed, it's English spelling that causes trouble!

Comment: There are lots of words like this. Beautiful, bountiful, plentiful, careful, fearful, dutiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Beautiful](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=beautiful)***  is the common spelling, "beautifull"   appears to be a less common variant or probably  just a misspelling which might derive from the adverbial form "beautifully":

> - mid-15c., "pleasing to the eye," ***from beauty + -ful.*** The beautiful people "the fashionable set" first attested 1964 in (where else?) "Vogue" (it also was the title of a 1941 play by U.S. dramatist William Saroyan). House Beautiful is from "Pilgrim's Progress," where it is a proper name of a place.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beautiful%2C%20beautifull%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeautifull%3B%2Cc0):*** beautiful vs beautifull

Comment: The spelling _beautifull_ was an alternate in the 15th and 16th centuries (e.g. see Burton's [_Anatomy of Melancholy_](https://books.google.com/books?id=NscIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA180&dq=%22beautifull%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaw52ovZzPAhUGbz4KHRD2C8oQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22beautifull%22&f=false)) but hasn't been accepted for 150 years or so.

Comment: @P.E. Dant - that is an interesting point that could have posted in an answer  to a potentially good  question instead of simply VTC it.

Comment: The archaic spelling of this word probably has no connexion to the OP's question. Any such contempory spelling is more likely to be a back-formation from _beautifully,_ as in your own answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - yes, I agree, but checking in Google the issue appears to be a common one, probably among NNS. So both my suggestion and your research could actually provide good reference for those who checked it in the future. IMO.

Comment: On my spell checker, *beautifull* is underlined in red; it seems the OP has manually included the erroneous spelling in their phone's dictionary. The OP is only asking which spelling is correct, and this question is easily answered in any dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It is not only a question of spell-checker, OP clearly refers to the unclear information about the usage of double ll in beatiful in google (where actually there  are a lot of sites which duscuss about it). A clear referened answer is always a good help.